# Reason for some generated methods in entity?

Tags: jhipster

I notice in my generated entity - (here called Pattern see far below), that there are some methods added that return the instance e.g.:

```
    public Pattern name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    ...

    public Pattern numCandles(Integer numCandles) {
        this.numCandles = numCandles;
        return this;
    }
```

what are the function of these above?

The entity

````
@Entity
..
public class Pattern implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "num_candles", nullable = false)
    private Integer numCandles;

    @Column(name = "jhi_desc")
    private String desc;
    ...

}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning the instance allows you to chain methods of your object like this :

```
Pattern p = new Pattern().name('x').numCandles(2);
```

These are called `fluent methods` and are used mainly in order to improve the readability of your source code